# Google Play Saved Games Android: result of Games.Snapshots.open()/resolveConflict() frequently has status 16

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

Methods `Games.Snapshots.open()` and `Games.Snapshots.resolveConflict()` (and maybe other too, haven't checked so far) sometimes (i.e., not always, but *frequently*) return the result with the status code equal to **16**.

There is no explanation of 16 in the [`GamesStatusCodes` documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesStatusCodes), nor in the [`Snapshots` documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots) itself. I tried looking at `GamesStatusCodes` in Android Studio, but there are present only codes from 0 to 15 and then 2000 and above. `GamesStatusCodes.getStatusString` also doesn't know 16 and outputs `Status code (16) not found!`

So what **16** does exactly mean, what causes it to appear and how should I handle it in my code? Or am I just missing something?

Comment: Speculation on my part - but it is possible there is a connection issue since 16 is also [API_UNAVAILABLE](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#API_UNAVAILABLE)? Or [CommonStatusCodes.Canceled](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes.html#CANCELED)

Comment: @ClaytonWilkinson Today this issue is gone completely (without any code changes). So you might be right and that was just a connection problem.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that 16 is found in the *CommonStatusCodes*, and it means **CANCELED**.

> The result was canceled either due to client disconnect or cancel().

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes